# C# winforms datagridviewcomboboxcolumn fill with List<string>

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I unable to fill combobox column with list values.

```
ISONameColumn.DataSource = Presenter.GetISONameList();
```

Such code creates a lot of rows (each new for the each record in the list).
Dropdown in each record has all necessary values.
But i need to have only a "NewRow" in the datagrid as usual.

Comment: What does the ISONameColumn refer to, the comboboxColumn or the datagridview itself?

Comment: yes ISONameColumn is a combobox column

Comment: Then this line of code is not generating those extra rows. Check where you are populating the datagridview.

Comment: i'm sorry, right, error was in another place

Comment: try to post full block of code... where all the object and variables are declared... coz we could not identify that what is `Presenter` and what `GetISONameList()` returns? if u getting exception then also post that exception in ur question so we can understand what is the actual problem and we can give better solution.